# I want to email google form responses automatically to multiple people based on form input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have the following script that at the moment sends an email to "email1" when the form is submitted I want to also cc in email2 & email3

Also at the moment it email it as just a list of answers eg

---

Email: email1@email.com

email 2 : email2@email.com

question number 1 : Option 1

question number 2 : Option 2

question number 3 : Option 3

---

Am I able to have it send the email out formatted like it does when it sends a copy to the person who submitted the form?

[![screenshot][1]][1]

````
var email1= "email1@email.com"
var email2= "email2@email.com"
var email2= "email3@email.com"

  MailApp.sendEmail(email1, "Report ", 
    e.response.getItemResponses()
      .reduce((body, item) => body += `${item.getItem().getTitle()} : ${item.getResponse()}\n`, 
      `Email: ${e.response.getRespondentEmail()}\n`)
  )
}```

[![Screenshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTcPe.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  const msg = e.values.filter((e,i) => i > 0 ).map((e,i) => `Question ${i + 1}: ${e}`).join('\n');
   GmailApp.sendEmail("email1","Subject",msg,{cc:"email2,email3"})
}
```

-[GmailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)